# Create a bootable CD that can can load USB drivers

Tags: bootable-media

I have an older laptop doesn't allow boot to USB. It has a CD drive instead of DVD player. How do I create a bootable CD that can then load USB so I can install Windows from my thumb drive?

Comment: Which OS are you trying to install? I know of a workaround for XP if you have a floppy drive built in or the bios allows booting from usb FDD and you have a usb floppy drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html) should let you do it - its a bootloader that runs off various external devices and should let you bootstrap a USB key or such.

However, older versions of windows probably will not boot off a USB key gracefully (there's tools like win2flash, but i've not had luck with them), and i doubt windows 7 or vista (which do support a USB install well) will run very well on a system that is old enough not to support USB boot.